# Using bitwise & instead of modulus operator to randomly sample integers from a range

Tags: c++, random, bit-manipulation, modulo, integer-division

I need to randomly sample from a uniform distribution of integers over the interval `[LB,UB]` in C++. To do so, I start with a "good" RN generator (from Numerical Recipes 3rd ed.) that uniformly randomly samples 64-bit integers; let's call it `int64()`.

Using the mod operator, I can sample from the integers in `[LB,UB]` by:

```
LB+int64()%(UB-LB+1);
```

The only issue with using the mod operator is the slowness of the integer division.  So, I then tried the method suggested [here](http://www.nr.com/forum/showthread.php?p=5273), which is:

```
LB + (int64()&(UB-LB))
```

The bitwise & method is about 3 times as fast.  This is huge for me, because one of my simulations in C++ needs to randomly sample about 20 million integers.

But there's 1 big problem.  When I analyze the integers sampled using the bitwise & method, they don't appear uniformly distributed over the interval `[LB,UB]`.  The integers are indeed sampled from `[LB,UB]`, but **only** from the even integers in that range.  For example, here is a histogram of 5000 integers sampled from [20,50] using the bitwise & method:
[image: Histogram of integers sampled using the bitwise & method]

By comparison, here is what a similar histogram looks like when using the mod operator method, which of course works fine:
[image]

What's wrong with my bitwise & method?  Is there any way to modify it so that both even and odd numbers are sampled over the defined interval?

Comment: It's easy to be fast if you don't have to be right. `<g>` The only cases where masking gives a valid distribution are when the size of the target range is a power of two.

Comment: Have you considered using a generator on the range (0,1), call it `u0_1()`, and multiplication: `LB+(int)(u0_1()*(UB-LB+1)`?  Modulo-based approaches generally yield non-uniform outcomes anyway, and should be avoided.

Comment: @pjs yes, that is what I will be using going forward.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @pjs Should the multiplication be `LB+(int)(u0_1()*(UB-LB+1))` or `LB+((int)u0_1())*(UB-LB+1)`?

Comment: @synaptik You want the former, the latter would always turn the u0_1() result into zero and thus yield LB. Sorry for the missing paren in my comment.

Comment: @pjs Thanks.  Right.  Sort of a dumb question -- I should have known that. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bitwise `&` operator looks at each pair of corresponding bits of its operands, performs an `and` using only those two bits, and puts that result in the corresponding bit of the result.

So, if the last bit of `UB-LB` is 0, then the last bit of the result is `0`. That is to say, if `UB-LB` is even then every output will be even.

The `&` is inappropriate to the purpose, unless `UB-LB+1` is a power of 2. If you want to find a modulus, then there's no general shortcut: the compiler will already implement `%` the fastest way it knows.

Note that I said no *general* shortcut. For particular values of `UB-LB`, known at compile time, there can be faster ways. And if you can somehow arrange for `UB` and `LB` to have values that the compiler can compute at compile time then it will use them when you write `%`.

By the way, using `%` does not in fact produce uniformly-distributed integers over the range, unless the size of the range is a power of 2. Otherwise there must be a slight bias in favour of certain values, because the range of your `int64()` function cannot be assigned equally across the desired range. It may be that the bias is too small to affect your simulation in particular, but bad random number generators have broken random simulations in the past, and will do so again.

If you want a uniform random number distribution over an arbitrary range, then use `std::uniform_int_distribution` from C++11, or the class of the same name in Boost.

Comment: Yes, I've been thinking about arranging for `LB` and `UB` to have a certain relation, and then using the sampling method but discarding the sampled variates that fall outside of the true desired range.

Comment: @synaptik: well, you might get lucky depending how close your runtime `UB-LB` is to the special values you use. But generally speaking the resampling is liable to be slower than division.

Comment: "but bad random number generators have broken random simulations in the past" you're 100% right about that.  That's one reason I'm using the NR3 method.  It has been soundly validated.

Comment: @synaptik: but then you're sabotaging it with the biassed `%` transformation. It's pretty easy to turn correctly-distributed random data into incorrectly-distributed data. Note that you can use `uniform_int_distribution` and still pass it a generator object that uses your sound algorithm from NR3, if you don't like the default random generator provided by `std`.

Comment: Yes, that's true.  (I'm using their RN generator for other purposes to sample uniform and normal variates, and in these other cases the statistical validity of the sampled distribution is more important.) But point taken.

Answer (score 2):

This works well if the range difference (`UB-LB`) is 2<sup>n</sup>-1, but won't work at all well if for example 2<sup>n</sup>.

Answer (score 1):

The two are equivalent only when the size of the interval is a power of two. In general y%x and y&(x-1) are not the same.

For example, x%5 produces numbers from 0 to 4 (or to -4, for negative x), but x&4 produces either 0 or 4, never 1, 2, or 3, because of how bitwise operators work...

Comment: Is there any way to avoid using the mod operator here and make the sampling faster?

Comment: Yes, but you will "lose bits" if the value is not 2<sup>n</n>-1.

Comment: Try your testing with, say, 52 and 20 instead of 50 and 20.

Comment: @MatsPetersson What do you mean?  Could you please explain the alternative?  (Sorry, I'm new to bitwise ops.)

Comment: Since an `&` operation produces "ones" only for the bits that are present on BOTH sides, the fewer "ones" you have on the right side, the fewer different values you can get. So for an arbitrary choice of range, you can't use this trick. And I can't think of any obvious suggestion as to an improvement of `%`. If `x` is the number of one-bits in your "right side", then the number of possible values is 2^x. So for 7 (0111) you get 2^3=8 different values. For 4 (0100) you get 2^1 = 2 different values.

Comment: I see.  Thanks for explaining.  So, perhaps (for smaller ranges), a lookup table holds the best hope of improving on the mod operator method.

Comment: You can compute the remainder with bit operations for specific classes of numbers but not in general. Think about it this way: if there was a faster way to compute x%y in general, the CPU would use it.

Comment: @Joni Yes, that's a good point.  The reason I began this search for an alternative to the mod operator is the statement in the text of Numerical Recipes 3rd edition that there are faster idioms that using `%` to sample uniform random integers over an interval.

Comment: For intervals of specific sizes yes. In general no. But in any case the sampling produced by % is not uniform.