# Use of bitwise operations instead of testing for even/odd

Tags: python, bitwise-operators

I'm trying to understand how this particular solution to prime decomposition (taken from http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Prime_decomposition#Python:_Using_floating_point ), and am a bit puzzled by the usage of bitwise operators in the definition of `step`

```
def fac(n):
    step = lambda x: 1 + (x<<2) - ((x>>1)<<1)
    maxq = long(floor(sqrt(n)))
    d = 1
    q = n % 2 == 0 and 2 or 3 
    while q <= maxq and n % q != 0:
        q = step(d)
        d += 1
    return q <= maxq and [q] + fac(n//q) or [n]
```

I understand what it does (multiply by x 3 and then add 1 if x is even and 2 if x is odd), but son't quite see why one would resort to bitwise operations in this context. Is there a reason, besides the obvious succinctness of this formulation, for the use of bitwise operators instead of a more explicit solution:

```
mystep = lambda x: (3 * x) + 1 if (x % 2 == 0) else (3 * x) + 2
```

If there is a good reason (say, `(x>>1)<<1` being more efficient than modulo arithmetic, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18674977/using-bitwise-instead-of-modulus-operator-to-randomly-sample-integers-from-a-r)), is there a general strategy for extracting the underlying logic from an expression with several bitwise operators?

---

### UPDATE

Following the suggestions in the answers, I timed both the version with step and with my step, and the difference is imperceptible:

```
 %timeit fac(600851475143)
1000 loops, best of 3: 306 µs per loop

%timeit fac2(600851475143)
1000 loops, best of 3: 307 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be an attempt to optimize around [branch misprediction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_misprediction). Modern CPUs are massively pipelined; they speculatively execute 10 or more instructions ahead. A conditional branch that near-randomly goes one way half the time and the other way half the time means the CPU will have to throw out 10 instructions worth of work half the time, making your work 5x as slow. At least with CPython, much of the cost of branch mispredictions is hidden in the overhead, but you can still easily find cases where they increase time by at least 12%, if not the 500% you can expect in C.

The alternative is that the author is optimizing for something even less relevant. On 70s and 80s hardware, replacing arithmetic operations with bitwise operations often led to huge speedups, just because the ALUs were simple and the compilers didn't optimize much. Even people who don't actually expect to get the same speedups today have internalized all the standard bit-twiddling hacks and use them without thinking. (Or, of course, the author could have just ported some code over from C or Scheme or some other language without really thinking about it, and that code could have been written decades ago when this optimization made a big difference.)

At any rate, this code is almost certainly optimizing in the wrong place. Defining a function to call every time in your inner loop, instead of just inlining the one-liner expression there, is adding far more overhead than 12%. And the fact that the code uses `step = lambda x: …` instead of `def step(x): …` implies pretty strongly that the author isn't comfortable in Python and doesn't know how to optimize for it. If you really want to make this go faster, there are almost certainly a lot of things that would make a whole lot more difference than which implementation you use for `step`.

That being said, the right thing to do with any optimization that you're not sure about is to test it. Implement it both ways, use `timeit` to see the difference, and if you don't understand the results, use a Python-level profiler or hardware-level performance counters (e.g., via `cachegrind`) or something else to get more information. From a very quick test of the original code against your alternative, throwing various numbers at it with IPython's `%timeit`, I got results ranging from .92x to 1.08x time for your version. In other words, it seems to be a wash…

Answer (score 0):

In theory, three bit shifts are more efficient than a single multiplication and a single division. In practice, such code should be profiled to ensure that the resulting optimization provides a sufficient speed boost to justify the loss of readability.

Any code that resorts to such optimizations should clearly document what the code does along with why the optimization was deemed useful, if only for the sake of future maintainers who may be tempted to replace the code with something more readable.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is Python, so a multiplication or division or bit shift probably entails several dozen instructions in addition to the respective ALU instruction.